jwt authentication problem "Un-authorization user access" issuses with status code 401
When I am checking with Thunder client, it gives me  jwt authentication problem "Un-authorization user access" issuses with status code 401
After JWT token generate successfully, it works fine
here is the code
app.get('/p3', async (req, res) => {
    let token = req.headers.authorization
    console.log('Main token: ' + token)

    if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Un-authorization' });
    }

    try {
        token = token.split(' ')[1];
        const user = jwt.verify(token, 'secret-key');
        console.log(user);
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid Token' });
    }

    return res.status(200).json({ message: 'I am a private route' });
})

But when I am trying to check the user identity with database, its shows error
{
  "message": "Un-authorization user access"
}

Route
http://localhost:4000/p4

here is the code
app.get('/p4', async (req, res) => {
    let token = req.headers.authorization
    console.log('Main token: ' + token)

    if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Un-authorization access' });
    }

    try {
        token = token.split(' ')[1];
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'secret-key');
        const user = await User.findById(decoded._id);
        console.log(user);

        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Un-authorization user access' });
        }

    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid Token' });
    }

    return res.status(200).json({ message: 'I am a private route' });
})

For reference here is the login route
app.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const { email, password } = req.body

    try {

        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        console.log(user)
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid Credentials, Please registered" });
        }

        const isMatchPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)   
        if (!isMatchPassword) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid Credentials, Please registered" });
        }

        delete user._doc.password
        delete user._doc._id
        delete user._doc.roles

        const token = jwt.sign(user._doc, 'secret-key', { expiresIn: '1h' })     

        return res.status(200).json({ message: "Login Successfull", token });
    } catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
});

I am trying with several user credentials but result the same

What is your JWT token format?

its, plain string format

The given value does not match with the key _id in the collection, therefore findById returns null, as a result, Express responds with 401 as it has been coded so.
..
const user = await User.findById(decoded._id);
…
return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Un-authorization user access' });

Please note that when the given value is either undefined or null, then mongoose will prepare and execute the following query, which also means that the given value - null does not match with _id.
User.findOne({ _id: null }, {})

Please pass a value which matches with the key _id in the collection.
Citation:
Model.findById()
